# Помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: delphi

Сам код [тут](http://pastebin.com/QJpCDimm) При вызове метода **LogIn** появляется ошибка:

`First chance exception at $00636D10. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00636d10: read of address 0x00000148'. Process Project5.exe (8220)`

Comment: А используете как ? Код вызова какой?
Объект точно создан ?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `fHTTP` не `nil`? Попробуйте в отладчике найти конкретную строку, которая вылетает.

Comment: Да вроде не может оно  там быть nil. В конструкторе все создается.

А вот строка

    ContentLength := 52;

мне не нравиться. Здесь может быть начало ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim, в конструкторе то осздаётся, но где гарантии что при использовании этого кода екземпляр объекта TDiscuzApi инициализирован, о чем собстно я стпросил в первом коментарии :)

Comment: это было бы уж слишком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в первую очередь сам TDiscuzApi проверьте на nil в месте вызова LogIn